# Save Date value in MySql

Tags: mysql, datetime, laravel-5.7

I am trying to save **Date** value in Database from Laravel. I set `MySql` column type `DateTime`. My controller code is like below

```
$seller->license_date = $request->license_date;
```

`1970-01-01 00:00:00` is saving in Database.

Comment: *1970-01-01 00:00:00 is saving in Database.* This is zero. Look why `0` instead of actual value is transferred.

Comment: That's a correct date format.. but is it a correct date?

Comment: @Akina, thanks. If I `dd($request->license_date)` & `dd($seller->license_date)` I am getting value. But why it is not saving in Database.

Comment: @tcadidot0, Thanks. It is not correct Date.

Answer (score 1):

Please check the value you are getting from dd($request->license_date) & dd($seller->license_date) if it is as the same format as 1970-01-01 00:00:00.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. No they are not `1970-01-01 00:00:00`. Thanks.

Comment: What are they? Please write here.

Comment: Try the following code please

$licenseDate = $request->license_date;
$licenseDateStr = strtotime($licenseDate);
$seller->license_date = date("Y-m-d", $licenseDateStr);

Also change the column type to only Date as you are not taking minute and second value.